# Facebook share link is not showing image

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

Please help me out, I am using Facebook share link with my site logo but it is not showing image, even I have proper image dimensions as per Facebook required, can you help me,

```
 http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=+100&p[title]=SundtBMI&p[url]=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.redsignal.biz%2Fclients%2Fdemo%2Fsundtbmi%2F&p[images][0]=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.redsignal.biz%2Fclients%2Fdemo%2Fsundtbmi%2Fskins%2Fdefault%2Fimages%2FSB_logo.png&p[images][1]=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.redsignal.biz%2Fclients%2Fdemo%2Fsundtbmi%2Fskins%2Fdefault%2Fimages%2FSB_logo.png&p[summary]=When+I+stand+before+God+at+the+end+of+my+life%2C+I+would+hope+that+I+would+not+have+a+single+bit+of+talent+left%2C+and+could+say%2C+%27I+used+everything+you+gave+me%27.Throughout+life+people+will+make+you+mad%2C+disrespect+you+and+treat+you+bad.+Let+God+deal+with+the+things+they+do%2C+cause+hate+in+your+heart+will+consume+you+too.How+far+you+go+in+life+depends+on+your+being+tender+with+the+young%2C+compassionate+with+the+aged%2C+sympathetic+with+the+striving+and+tolerant+of+the+weak+and+strong.+Because+someday+in+your+life+you+will+have+been+all+of+these.When+I+stand+before+God+at+the+end+of+my+life%2C+I+would+hope+that+I+would+not+have+a+single+bit+of+talent+left%2C+and+could+say%2C+%27I+used+everything+you+gave+me%27.Throughout+life+people+will+make+you+mad%2C+disrespect+you+and+treat+you+bad.+Let+God+deal+with+the+things+they+do%2C+cause+hate+in+your+heart+will+consume+you+too.How+far+you+go+in+life+depends+on+your+being+tender+with+the+young%2C+compassionate+with+the+aged%2C+sympathetic+with+the+striving+and+tolerant+of+the+weak+and+strong.+Because+someday+in+your+life+you+will+have+been+all+of+these.When+I+stand+before+God+at+the+end+of+my+life%2C+I+would+hope+that+I+would+not+have+a+single+bit+of+talent+left%2C+and+could+say%2C+%27I+used+everything+you+gave+me%27.Throughout+life+people+will+make+you+mad%2C+disrespect+you+and+treat+you+bad.+Let+God+deal+with+the+things+they+do%2C+cause+hate+in+your+heart+will+consume+you+too.How+far+you+go+in+life+depends+on+your+being+tender+with+the+young%2C+compassionate+with+the+aged%2C+sympathetic+with+the+striving+and+tolerant+of+the+weak+and+strong.+Because+someday+in+your+life+you+will+have+been+all+of+these.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this way of sharing is being phased out. The new method is documented here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

So to do a direct url share you will need to use a link like this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
  app_id=458358780877780&
  link=https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&
  picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&
  name=Facebook%20Dialogs&
  caption=Reference%20Documentation&
  description=Using%20Dialogs%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&
  redirect_uri=https://mighty-lowlands-6381.herokuapp.com/
```

Note that you will need to create an app to get an app_id.

Comment: yes thanks i followed it, for this app_id is required so i created it as well. thanks for your answer.